# Stored procedure: set output parameter from first row of select

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server 2014 that selects some rows from a table with pagination, along with total row count:

```
SELECT 
    [...], COUNT(*) OVER () AS RowCount
FROM 
    [...] 
WHERE 
    [...] 
ORDER BY 
    [...]
    OFFSET ([..]) ROWS FETCH NEXT 3 ROWS ONLY
```

Output:

```
+----+------+----------+
| ID | Name | RowCount |
+----+------+----------+
| 1  | Bob  | 55       |
| 123| John | 55       |
| 99 | Jack | 55       |
+----+------+----------+
```

I would like to return results with actual data only, passing RowCount in an output parameter.

```
+----+------+
| ID | Name |
+----+------+
| 1  | Bob  |
| 123| John |
| 99 | Jack |
+----+------+

@OutRowCount = 55
```

I tried with a CTE, but CTE is available only within the first SELECT:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT [...], COUNT(*) OVER () AS RowCount
    FROM [...] 
    WHERE [...] 
    ORDER BY [...]
        OFFSET ([..]) ROWS FETCH NEXT 3 ROWS ONLY
)
SELECT
    ID, Name
FROM
    CTE
SET @OutRowCount = (SELECT TOP 1 RowCount FROM CTE) -- here CTE is no longer defined
```

How can I do this? I think I can use temp table but I wonder if in this case performance might be an issue.

Comment: A CTE is only able to be referenced in the statement it was *defined* it, not the first `SELECT`. The *final* part of the statement doesn't even need to be a `SELECT`, if could be a DML statement as well. For what you want here, however, a temporary table would likely be a better choice. If you paging the data, and it has a large amount of rows, it will likely be worth while ensuring you index the temporary table as well, to allow the ordering to be much easier for the data engine.

Comment: There's no cunning way around that, you'll need to store the result of the query in a temp table/table variable and then return the required columns and get the count separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Larnu and @Stu, I solved this using a table variable, this way:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProc
    @OutRowCount INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @TempTbl TABLE (
        ID INT, 
        Name VARCHAR(MAX),
        RowCount INT
        )

    INSERT INTO 
        @TempTbl
    SELECT
        ID,
        Name,
        COUNT(*) OVER() AS TotRighe
    FROM
        MyTable 
    WHERE 
        [...]
    ORDER BY 
        Name
        OFFSET ([...]) ROWS FETCH NEXT 3 ROWS ONLY

    SELECT
        ID, 
        Name
    FROM 
        @TempTbl

    SET @OutRowCount = ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1 RowCount FROM @TempTbl), 0)
    
END
```

Comment: Aside: One of the _features_ of using `output` parameters is that the values aren't available until after the recordset(s) have been read by the client, i.e. the queries have finished executing.

Comment: Yes, I noticed this but I thought it was related to LINQ/Entity Framework. In my code I overcome this by calling ".ToList()", thus forcing db read operations.

Answer (score 0):

The "total row count" you have in mind is a bit unclear. Typically when paging you also display to total number of (filtered) rows, e.g. "Showing 3 of 42 Blue Widgets". That doesn't involve `Max`.

A CTE can have multiple queries, e.g.:

```
with
  AllRows as ( -- All of the filtered rows.
    select ..., Count(*) over (...) as RowCount
      from ...
      where ... -- Filter criteria. ),
  SinglePage as ( -- One page of filtered rows.
    select ...
      from AllRows
      order by ... -- Order here to get the correct rows in the page.
      offset (...) rows fetch next 3 rows only )
select SP.Id, SP.Name,
  ( select Count(42) from AllRows ) as TotalRowCount -- Constant over all rows.
  from SinglePage
  order by ...; -- Keep the rows in the desired order.
```

Re: `SET @OutRowCount = (SELECT TOP 1 RowCount FROM CTE)`

Note that `TOP 1` without `order by` isn't guaranteed to pick the row you have in mind.

Comment: Thank you HABO, RowCount in this case is the total rows returned by the query, without pagination. In my example, I have 55 rows, but only 3 are selected. I need to pass RowCount to calculate page count.
I can safely use TOP 1 because every row has the same value for RowCount.
That said, my question if focused on extracting a value and pass it through an output parameter, rather than doing pagination (this actually works the way I need).